# Converting ArrayLike Object

Tags: javascript

Isn't there any ways for converting array-like objects into array so that all array methods can be used with it?see here:

```
[].prototype.forEach.call("maizere",fn)
```

likewise for every array-like objects,

what i want is ,to use forEach loop directly on this "maizere" string.But before that i need to convert it into an array .Is there any possibility or any trick that works for all array-like objects.Thank u.

Comment: Do you really need a single solution that works for all different types, or just strings?

Comment: What type of function might be called with either a string, NodeList, arguments, etc. and needs to process them all as arrays? This seems like a strange requirement.

Comment: @Barmar not strange,i just want to use all array method into array-like objects without any deeper code but apply directly on them.So is there any method or trick that will convert array-like objects to array .So that i can use that method/trick whenever i want to use array-like objects as array and use array methods without any fear

Comment: You're not satisfied with the answer that Blender gave? I don't know anything better.

Comment: everybody here seems to know what the term "array-like object" referes to, cool. For understanding the question better, what is it. I woudl be nice to give a reference to what is meant by "array-like object". Maybe this then also would help in even making clearer the question. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it into `slice` instead of `forEach` (`slice` will just make an array out of it):

```
Array.prototype.slice.call("maizere").map(function(l) {
    return l + 'foo';
}).forEach(function(l) {
    console.log(l);
});
```

It'll work for array-like objects like `NodeList`s, `arguments` and strings.

Comment: thank u ,that was helpful.Also will this method work for any arry-like object